# referencing an attribute in a windows path string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have the following execute in chef:

```
#execute
execute 'service-api install' do
  command 'c:\buildinfo\service-api\api\approot\web-#{node['default']['env']}.cmd'
end
```

its running in windows and #{node['default']['env']} is an attribute that I am trying to reference in the path string above.

When I run this I get the following error:

```
> SyntaxError
> ==> default: -----------
> ==> default: C:\vagrant-chef\319622f1791bb50a8f9441fd4c1ff806\cookbooks\djcm_paypal_win\recipes\installService.rb:76:
> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
> ==> default: ...api\approot\web-#{node['default']['env']}.cmd'
```

If I try:

```
 #execute
    execute 'service-api install' do
      command "c:\buildinfo\service-api\api\approot\web-#{node['default']['env']}.cmd"
    end
```

The slashes display in a different color(escape character?) and I get the following error:

```
[execute] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 command "c:\buildinfo ervice-api\api\approotweb-integration.cmd"
```

So it messes up around slashes but gets the attribute. How can I give an attribute in a string with slashes ?

edit 1 :
 I tried both double slashes and the other solution, even though it now tries to find the right path but still gives a failure even though the file is present at that exact location and I can run it manually. Any ideas ?

the error now :

```
* execute[service-api install] action run
==> default:     [execute] The system cannot find the path specified.
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:     Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[service-api install]'
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:     
==> default:     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:     ------------------------------------
==> default:     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default:     ---- Begin output of c:\buildinfo\service-api\api\approot\web-integration.cmd ----
==> default:     STDOUT: 
==> default:     STDERR: The system cannot find the path specified.
==> default:     ---- End output of c:\buildinfo\service-api\api\approot\web-integration.cmd ----
==> default:     Ran c:\buildinfo\service-api\api\approot\web-integration.cmd returned 1
```

Comment: Try using double slashes `c:\\buildinfo\\service-api...` and so forth.

Comment: @vee - check edit please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single quotes will not allow interpolation. Using double quotes will make the backslashes have special meaning, so [`\b` means "backspace"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Backslash_Notation).

You can compromise by using the `%` operator to add content `printf`-style:

```
command('c:\buildinfo\service-api\api\approot\web-%s.cmd' % node['default']['env'])
```

Comment: yes, the file exists.If I run the path in the system itself, it works. :/

Comment: Doesn't something like `command` run it on the remote machine?

Comment: Are you sure? That looks suspiciously like a remote command execution attempt.

Comment: Still pretty sure that's intended to execute remote commands. That's what tools like Chef are all about. Make sure that file exists on your target machine.